# How to use/define tag <> in php variable?

Tags: php

I want to define variable like this.

```
$dhara = "<a href="$media['url']"><img src="$media['url']" alt="test.jpg"  class="alignnone size-full" /></a>";
```

But this gives me this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$dhara' (T_VARIABLE)

How to do this? I want to define or use varialbe like this:

```
 $dhara = "<a href="$media['url']">"
```

Comment: When you say "like this," what do you mean? As it stands it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: What do you want ? A string containing `<a href="$media['url']"><img src="$media['url']" alt="test.jpg"  class="alignnone size-full" /></a>` ? Or a string containing some specific values of `$media` ?

Comment: @HeenaRajshree you got some advance?

Answer (score -1):

I tested your code; if I am right there is concatenation (`.`) error in your program. You must use concatenation if you're adding variable with string or adding two variables.

Eg `$merge  = $first_var .$second_var`

You must write in that way:

";
    echo $dhare;
?>

Happy to help.
 fb.com/waytoprashant